# Resizing a jpeg from a buffer to another buffer

Tags: c++, jpeg, image-resizing

I read other questions/answers similar to this one, but they either :

- Read/Write jpeg files
- Use .NET

In my case, I have a buffer (in this example, an unsigned char*), that contains a jpeg. It means it looks like that :

```
FF D8 FF E0 ...
```

and not

```
my_image.jpg
```

I want to find a library that would resize this jpeg and put the output in another buffer.

Example :

```
SuperLibrary::resize_jpeg(jpeg_buffer, resized_jpeg_buffer, 640, 480);
```

Or even :

```
SuperLibrary::Image my_jpeg = SuperLibray::Image(jpeg_buffer);
my_jpeg.resize(640,480);
my_jpeg.write(resized_jpeg_buffer);
```

Also, I would like something quite simple. CImg looked perfect at first, but it can only load/save jpeg from a file. (so, no openCV please, unless you can prove that I can get it to resize my jpegs in less than a week of going though documentation on CVMatrix)

Comment: Perhaps http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/ is what you're looking for.

Comment: Does this buffer store the compressed data and you want to apply a transformation on them or you want to manipulate the pixel raw data values?

Comment: I dont care about manipulating pixem myself. I just need to apply a transformation to the picture as a whole, no matter how it is done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ImageMagick` (and more specifically, the `Magick++` bindings to it) will do this. There's some API doc [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#Image%20Manipulation%20Methods). An example of how to do this (note that I haven't compiled this to check, so there are likely errors):

```
#include <Magick++.h> 
#include <iostream> 

using namespace Magick; 

int main(int argc,char **argv) 
{ 
  InitializeMagick(*argv);
  unsigned char* img_data;
  //Fill in img_data

  Blob b(img_data, image_data_len);
  Image img(b); 
  img.resize("640x480");

  Blob resized;
  master.write(resized); 

  unsigned char* img_data_resized = new unsigned_char[resized.length()];
  std::copy(resized.data(), resized.data() + resized.length(), img_data_resized);

  //Do whatever you want with resized image data...

  delete[] img_data_resized;
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: I will give it a try. I have to admit that the whole "InitializeMagick" is one of the reason I did not want to use ImageMagick to begin with. But I guess there are no other way.

Comment: Connecting to my account for the first time in years. I can confirm that ImageMagick is exactly what I needed.